# Save URL into database

Tags: urls

I apologize in advance. I don't know even how to ask, what to ask, or what search for.

Let say users can access my website from different URLs.

> https://www.mywebsite.com/something1 
>   https://www.mywebsite.com/something2 
>   https://www.mywebsite.com/something3

How can I those "something" **save into DB**? Or another way to **store** those "something" variables.

I want have overview of all attempts to access my website.

What can I do? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have **simple data**, you can use [add_option](https://wp-kama.com/function/add_option) function to save the data to the [wp_options](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) database table. You can pass an array, it will be serialized automatically. Just pass the array to the function in the second argument, and specify the option name in the first argument (something like `all_visits`).

   And then you can retrieve it later using [get_option](https://wp-kama.com/function/get_option) function — just pass option name (in our case, `all_visits`) as the first argument. The value will be retrieved from the wp_options database table and unserialized automatically.
2. If you want to save **complex data**, take a look at the [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class — it contains a set of functions used to interact with a database.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!